# Prime decomposition program works slower than it should work

Tags: c++

my program will simply do a Prime decomposition for a number. I guess things work fine here except it's a little slow. for example for a number like 9999997 i don't get an answer. I think it can be a bit more optimized.
my program examples:
input : 100
output : 2^5*2^2
or
input : 13
output : 13
or
input : 98
out put : 2^7*2

```
using namespace std;

int getInput();
void caculation(int x);
bool isFirst(int x);

int main() {

  int n = getInput();
  if (isFirst(n) == false && n != 0) {
    caculation(n);
    cout << endl;
  } else {
    cout << n;
    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
//Functions
int getInput() {
  int x {};
  cin >> x;
  return x;
};
void caculation(int x) {
  bool con = false;
  int j {0};
  int star = 0;
  int sum = x;
  for (int i {sqrt(x)}; sum > 1; i--) {
    if (isFirst(i) == true) {
      while (sum % i == 0) {
        sum = sum / i;
        j++;
        con = true;
      }
      if (con == true) {
        star += 1;
        if (star > 1) cout << "*";
        cout << i;
        if (j != 1) cout << "^" << j;
        j = 0;
        con = false;
      }
    }
  }

}
bool isFirst(int x) {
  if (x <= 1) return false;
  int h = 1;
  for (int i = 2; i <= x; i++) {
    if (x % i == 0) {
      h++;
      if (h > 2) return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: Bad formatting... Looks like your complexity is in n*n. Use the Sieve of Eratosthenes instead.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki sorry, done

Comment: @JohnMurray Thanks but actually i used that in my code but even with that it doesn't works well for large numbers (time limit exceeded)

Comment: You are considering the candidate divisors `i` from sqrt(x) to 2. This forces you to check primality of each `i`. By doing it from 2 to sqrt(n), you can avoid this test on `i`.

Comment: @Damien Thank you very much man. that really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this realization. std::map used here to store factors data.
For example: 6860 = 2^2 * 5 * 7^3 will be presented as map:{ {2,2}, {5,1}, {7,3} } where key is prime factor and value is factors degree.

This program runs much faster than yours, It decomposes the number 9999999997 instantly.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

std::map<int64_t, int64_t> decomp(int64_t n)
{
    std::map<int64_t, int64_t> factors;

    int64_t z = 2;
    while(z * z <= n)
        if(n % z == 0)
        {
            factors[z]++;
            n /= z;
        }
        else
            z++;

    if(n > 1)
        factors[n]++;

    return factors;
}

void print_factors(std::map<int64_t, int64_t> factors)
{
    string ch = "";
    for(auto a : factors)
    {
        if(a.second > 1)
            cout << ch << a.first << "^" << a.second;
        else
            cout << ch << a.first;
        ch = "*";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int64_t n = getInput();
    auto factors = decomp(n);
    print_factors(factors);
}
```

Comment: Whoa This is much faster solution! great job

Comment: @Jimmy Thanks, Jimmy!

Answer (score -1):

I was not able to follow your algorithm.  Here is a solution which handles your larger number example and goes a little faster.  Explanation of the algorithm is in the comments.

```c++
// Program to print all prime factors
# include <stdio.h>
# include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

int getInput() {
    int x {};
    std::cin >> x;
    return x;
};

void PrintPrimeFactors(int n)
{
    int power_count;
    bool factor_found = false;

    // Find home many times n is divisible by 2
    if(n%2 == 0) {

        // count the number of times that n can be divided by 2
        power_count = 1;
        n = n / 2;
        while (n % 2 == 0) {
            n = n / 2;
            power_count++;
        }
        printf("%d^%d", 2, power_count);
        factor_found = true;
    }

    // At this point, if n > 1, then the original n was an odd number.
    // We have already gotten rid of all the 2's, so we can start with i = 3.
    // i represents the starting point to test for more primes (greater than 2)
    // At this point, we know that n is odd, so,
    //     we can skip even numbers to get a little bit more efficiency
    for (int i = 3; i*i <= n; i = i+2)
    {
        if(n%i == 0) {
            // count the number of times that n can be divided by i
            power_count = 1;
            n = n / i;
            while (n % i == 0) {
                n = n / i;
                power_count++;
            }

            // we use 'factor_found' to know if we have a prior factor, causing us to 
            // print an '*' prior to this factor
            if(factor_found) {
                printf(" * ");
            }
            printf("%d^%d", i, power_count);
            factor_found = true;

        }
    }

    // This condition is to handle the case when n
    // is a prime number greater than 2
    if (n > 2) {
        if(factor_found) {
            printf(" * ");
        }
        printf("%d", n);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n = getInput();
    PrintPrimeFactors(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "At this point, if n > 1, then the original n was an odd number." I don't think this is right.

Comment: Also, `i <= sqrt(n)` is subject to rounding error. Much better (and faster) is `i * i <= n`.

Comment: And of course `n` can't be 2 at the end (but that doesn't invalidate your code).

Comment: @TonyK:  I agree with you on the sqrt(n) issue and have edited that.

Comment: @TonyK:  If n > 1 ... at that point -- Yes.  That is true.  I have divided out all powers of 2.  So, if original n is a power of 2, then n is now equal to 1.  However, if n was not a power of 2, then the current n is either an odd prime number or an odd composite number.   So, if n at that point is > 1, then the original n must have been an odd number.

Comment: @TonyK:  "And of course n can't be 2 at the end..." Correct.  n is not 2 at that point, but it could be 3.  I could check for n > 2 or n >= 3.  Not sure that one would be more efficient than the other.  If I don't check for this, then I will miss the final prime factor.  ie., if I input 7, then the program will give no output.  if I input 10, then the program will only print 2 and will miss the *5 at the end.

Comment: If `n` started as 10, say, then it will be 5 when it gets to that point. And 5 > 1, but the original `n` was nevertheless not an odd number.

Comment: `i*i < n` is wrong! It has to be `i*i <= n`, in case `n` is a the square of a prime.